# Changing the password of an AD user in VSTS online

Tags: active-directory, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, azure-devops

I changed the AD password from a user in Active Diretory. This Active Directory is integrated with Azure and the Azure account has Visual Studio Online enabled. All the users in Visual Stuidio Online are users from Active Directory and all of them have access. When the user tries to login in the Visual Studio Online, the new password is not valid, only the old one. What needs to be done ?

Comment: Did you enable password synchronization in Azure AD Connect ?

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something, it is working now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. If possible, you can post your answer under this question . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to [@wayne-yang-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8514432/wayne-yang-msft). All I had to do was enable password synchronization in Azure AD Connect.